# Length Validation in Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

How to do length validation in Mule Dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
(payload default []) map {
    Field1:$.Field11,
    Field2:$.Field22,
    Field3:$.Field33,
    Field4:$.Field44
}
```

I want to do validation like `max Length of Field22 < 20`

How to achieve this in Mule Dataweave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a when condition on an invidual field using the sizeOf operator:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
(payload default []) map {
    Field1:$.Field11,
    (Field2: $.Field22) when (sizeOf $.Field22) < 20,
      Field3:$.Field33,
    Field4:$.Field44
}
```